# Post data from external domain to prestashop modules

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.5

I will be developing a **prestashop module** to which i want to `POST` data from my external source. I went through their documentaion and it is mentioned there that external visitors are prohibited to load `mymodule.php.` file directly. Is there any legitimate way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is two ways to do something depends on customer action:

- bind it with [hook](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Managing+Hooks)
- create [controller](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Controllers+within+PrestaShop) e.g. for manual call

also [Creating a PrestaShop Module](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+PrestaShop+Module) doc's.

Comment: I understand. But, in their documentation, they have suggested to begin `mymodule.php` with the following code,
    `if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
      exit;`
And this is to avoid requests from external source.
If i will not write these lines, will my module get rejected by prestashop ?

Comment: @Gaurang Deshpande create a php file inside your module folder and create your module object inside the newly created php file and call the required functions and process the data. And then give the link to acces this php script from external app. So that your module is not directly accessed and the site is secure.

Comment: Hello,
I understand. But my concern is whether my module will be rejected if i not include `if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) exit;` as the **first line** of `mymodule.php`

Comment: `mymodule.php` just contains class declaration, to do something helpful using this class you can use **Gofenice Technologies** answer or hooks/controllers